# Anyone Been Through the .NET Program with SetFocus?

Tags: .net, education

By day, I'm a PowerBuilder developer.

By night, I dream of being a .NET developer.  Sure, I can self-teach mostly everything I need, but I also love classroom learning and 'earning' my education.

I am considering 'attending' the SetFocus course for .NET development.  My hesitations?  It's expensive.

Anyone?  Feel free to tell me its a crazy idea, regardless of the money.  I'm interested in your opinions.

Comment: I hired a guy from SetFocus once and he was a horrible coder and an even worse employee. I don't know if that is any reflection on the program but I have never seen so much spaghetti code in my life. I looked at his courseware and I wasn't very impressed with it; I think any decent intro to programming book can get you started just as well; I think they do work to place you though which is nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your Powerbuilder experience will help you more than the school will because you're already a developer. Save your money, teach yourself and start applying for .NET positions. Some teams are supporting Powerbuilder apps and you'd be a great fit if you can walk in and start maintaining them. The team I'm on now supports legacy Powerbuilder 7 code and just last week my manager asked if I had Powerbuilder experience.

Answer (score 0):

I'm happy to see you are interested in The Master's Program and I understand your concerns.  To date over 2000 people have successfully completed the program.  A number of them have provided unsolicted feedback on our LInkedIn page.  Feel free to check it out  http://www.linkedin.com/company/setfocus/products

I'm more than happy to answer any questions you have directly.  Feel free to reach out to me anytime.

Mike Landau
SetFocus CEO

Comment: Hi Mike. If you want to leave your contact information up for people to see, please put it in your profile. Thanks.